# jQuery UI (toggle) Drop Down Menu Overlaps To Other Menus

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

The menus are overlapping onto other menus. When you click the first menu "About Us" it opens. But when you click "Products", the "About Us" don't close so the "Products" menu overlaps to "About Us" menu.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/ncTQr/)**

HTML

```
<body>
<nav>
   <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="menuabout"><a>About</a>
             <ul class="subnav01 clearfix">
                  <li><a href="#">About One</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About Two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About Three</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About Four</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About Five</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About Six</a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menuproducts"><a>Products</a>
             <ul class="subnav02 clearfix">
                  <li><a href="#">Product One</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product Two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product Three</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product Four</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product Five</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product Six</a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>             
</nav>
```

​

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: darkgray;
}

.nav {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1;
}

.nav li:nth-child(5) {
    margin: 0;
}

.nav li a {
    height: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.subnav01, .subnav02 {
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    left: -300px;
    display: none;
}
.subnav01 li, .subnav02 li {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.subnav01 li a, .subnav02 li a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: dodgerblue;
    height: 10px;
    display:block;
}

.subnav01 li a:hover, .subnav02 li a:hover {
    background: dimgray;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.active > a {
    background: dodgerblue !important;
}​
```

JS/jQuery/jQuery UI/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".menuabout").on("click", function(){
        $(".subnav01").toggle ("slide", {direction: "right"}, "slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
    $(".menuproducts").on("click", function(){
        $(".subnav02").toggle ("slide", {direction: "right"}, "slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can try something like this. I've changed you class to `menu` for all menu elements, so you can use one function for all of them

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ncTQr/35/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".menu").on("click", function(){
        deactivateAll(this);
        toggle(this);
    });

    function deactivateAll(current) {
        $( "li" ).each(function( index, elem ){
            if (elem != current && $(elem).hasClass("active")) {
                toggle(elem);
            }
        });
    }

    function toggle(elem) {
        $(elem).find("ul").toggle ("slide", {direction: "right"}, "slow");
        $(elem).toggleClass("active");
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to slide to left and then hide the menus when its not needed? Because when you click it again to hide the menu its just repeating the animation but still shows again the menu.

Comment: I see what you mean. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/ncTQr/35/ - I've added a check that elem != current. I've also updated an answer

Comment: It still doesn't hide the menus when clicked the second time. For example I click the "Products" then I want to hide it again, so I should click it again, but it's not hiding.

Comment: Hallelujah! Thank you very much man! Can I remove the subnav's numbering with out ruining it?

Comment: Yup got it! I don't need the subnavs' to be numbered! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This works: ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncTQr/8/))

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".menuabout").on("click", function(){
        reset();
        $(".subnav01").toggle ("slide", {direction: "right"}, "slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
    $(".menuproducts").on("click", function(){
        reset();
        $(".subnav02").toggle ("slide", {direction: "right"}, "slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
    function reset() {
        $("ul.nav li").removeClass("active");
        $("ul.nav li ul").hide();        
    }
});​
```

Also you could refactor your code a bit so that it doesn't repat so much. Adding more root navigation elements would mean copying your code every time :)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! But is there a way that when I click for example "About Us" menu and "Products" menu is visible can the "About Us" menu be hidden/slide to left like me example above? I mean if you click "About Us" twice it should slide to left?

Comment: I created more classes because when I click "products" the menu for "about us" also opens. I don't know how to do it with only 1 class for all the drop down menus.

Comment: See Roman's answer. He's refactored it nicely and also slides your menus right instead of just hiding